# Request in Flask from a Form in HTML is returning None, what did i do wrong?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

i want to be able to get the the user name from a form and append it to a confirmation page but it keeps returning none

below is the html form

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="post" novalidate>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
      <label>Phone Number</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea rows="5" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
      <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
</form>
```

and the flask code is below

```
@app.route("/contact")
def contact():
    return render_template("contact.html")


@app.route("/form-entry", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def receive_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        return f"<h1>{name} Successfully sent your message</h1>"
```

i tried using request.form["name"] but it comes back with a bad request error

Answer (score 1):

The template as defined, when rendered through the `/contact` endpoint, the following line (unrelated attributes replaced with ellipsis):

```html
<form ... action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="post" ...>
```

Renders to

```html
<form ... action="/contact" method="post" ...>
```

Submitting the form will again hit the same `/contact` endpoint, which does not accept the `POST` method as the default list of accept `methods` was used for that.  This resulted in the Bad Request error as reported.

Given the intended target is supposed to be the `received_data` function, hooked to the `/form-entry` endpoint, the intended argument for `url_for` in the template should be `'receive_data'`, i.e.

```
<form ... action="{{ url_for('receive_data') }}" method="post" ...>
```

which would result in this rendering:

```html
<form ... action="/form-entry" method="post" ...>
```

When submitting that form, the intended end-point should be used and the message should be rendered without issues.